# "point me the right direction" or "point me to the right direction"?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

"point me the right direction" or "point me to the right direction"? Which one is correct and sounds more natural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More natural than either is

> Point me **in** the right direction.

Indeed this is a standard set phrase.

> Point me the right direction.

feels incorrect, although I think it is in fact correct grammar.

> Point me to the right **path**.

seems fine, one points someone to an external thing, such as a path or an office or house, but  one points someone in a direction, the image is of soemoen guiding another so that the one guided turns in the desired direction, I think.

Comment: Thanks David for the answer. If it's other nouns in the example, like "point him my book" or "point her the right way", are these correct usages?

Comment: @Ogrish Man Use "point him **to** my book". but "way" is like "direction" and would not need "to". Most nouns would take "to".